# Verify http requests made by android app while running espresso

Tags: android, http, get, android-espresso

While running UI Espesso tests I would like to also verify if the app is making correct http requests (e.g triggered by a button press). Currently using OkHttpClient client to make the requests.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something? I like to use Wiremock to mock http requests and check that the app have done the correct request. You must use the standalone version or you will get some issues with HttpClient.

For more information see http://wiremock.org/index.html